# How to execute Robot Test Cases in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, robotframework

I am struggling on how to execute Robot Test cases in Jenkins. My project setup is as follows:
Source Code management: GIT
Build: Execute Shell

And this is what i have tried in the shell:
python -m robot.run TestCases

But i am getting the following output errros:

```
Commit message: "robot framework start"
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk 9adbfb88132f5ec3fceb0c9863eab141f93d29f6 # timeout=10
[SampleJob] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins14811373557342144066.sh
+ python -m robot.run TestCases
==============================================================================
TestCases                                                                     
==============================================================================
TestCases.Login TC :: This test is for open login and close browser           
==============================================================================
Register Form                                                         | FAIL |
Setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process


Also teardown failed:
No browser is open.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Choose Radio Button                                                   | FAIL |
Setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process


Also teardown failed:
No browser is open.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TestCases.Login TC :: This test is for open login and close browser   | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 0 passed, 2 failed
2 tests total, 0 passed, 2 failed
==============================================================================
TestCases.TC002 FetchData :: This test is for open login and close browser    
==============================================================================
Test                                                                  | FAIL |
Setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

This is an example test in the folder TestCases

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Resource    ../Resources/BeforeTest.robot
Documentation    This test is for open login and close browser
Test Setup    Start Browser and Maximize
Test Teardown    Close Browser Window
*** Variables ***
${Browser}
${URL}

*** Test Cases ***
Register Form

    Enter user, mail and pass    thisistheusername    thisistheemail    thisisthepassword

Choose Radio Button
  Select Radio Button    add_type    home   
  Select From List By Index    name:sex    2    

*** Keywords ***
Enter user, mail and pass
    [Arguments]    ${username}    ${email}    ${password}   
    Input Text    name=fld_username    ${username}      
    Input Text    xpath=//input[@type='email']    ${email}
    Input Text    name=fld_password    ${password}
```

When i execute the code from terminal everything works as expected.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve] of a test file with a single test that is as small as possible and which reproduces this error. Clearly you're already able to run test cases on jenkins, so the question is, what is it about the test case that is causing it to fail.

Comment: Hi this is the repo, thanks for your help https://github.com/hadrianjmnz90/RobotFramework.git

Comment: The repo is useless, as it may go away or change in the future, rendering this question useless to others. Code needs to be in the question. You should start with the absolute simplest test possible - for example, open a browser and take a screenshot. Until you get that part working, there's no point in having anything else in the test file.

Comment: I added an example of a testcase i have, another comment is that everything is working when i run the code from terminal, so i do not know if apart from the code there might be another jenkins set up i am missing, thanks.

Comment: It would help if you made that even smarter. Someone who wants to help shouldn't have to download a bunch of files. You should be able to put everything in a single file without any dependencies other than perhaps `SeleniumLibrary`.

Comment: The robot log generated by jenkins should have more details about why the tests are failing.